# Adding a Footer to a flextable object with column headers that include spaces

Tags: ms-word, flextable

I'm attempting to add a footer to a flextable object, but I'm running into difficulties when that object has column headers that include spaces. Here is an some code as an example:

```
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)


example <- head(cars)
names(example) <- c("Speed (MPH)", "Distance (Ft)")

example %>%
  regulartable %>%
  add_footer(`Speed (MPH)` = "Blah Blah Blah Blah") %>%
  merge_at(part = "footer")
```

This code produces a flextable object with {{Speed (MPH)}} in the footer (and not "Blah Blah Blah Blah" as I specified). I am using flextable version 0.4.3.

How does one add a footer to a flextable with column headers that include spaces? I know that I can give the columns one word placeholder names and then change the column headers using set_header_labels, but I'm hoping for a way to do this without changing the original column headers.

Comment: This has been fixed in the version 0.4.4

Comment: The specific example provided above now works in 0.4.4, but if you change `Distance (Ft)` to `Distance Ft` it still throws an error: `Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : <text>:1:9: unexpected symbol 1:Distance Ft^` Not sure why it works with space + parenthesis and not space+text. Just grabbed 0.4.5.001 from Github and that appears to solve the problem.  Thanks!